# nginx-quic(support http3) 0-rtt not work when use multi server blocks

Tags: nginx, http3

To support http3, i build nginx-quic and configure multi server blocks for vhost, my nginx.conf enabled all importmant params but http3's early-data still don't take effect，nginx log contains: `quic no early keys, ignoring packet while decrypting packet`, unless set 'worker_processes' as only 1, i think the reason is 'ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:100m' didn't take effect, does anyone know? thanks

my nginx.conf key configurations are follows :

```
http {

    log_format quic '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http3"';

    error_log  /data/log/nginx_quic_error.log;
    error_log  /data/log/nginx_quic_error.log debug;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
    ssl_early_data on;
    ssl_session_tickets on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;


    keepalive_timeout  65;

   server {
      listen 443 ssl http2;
      listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
      listen 443 http3 reuseport;
      listen [::]:443 http3 reuseport;
      server_name *.ap.staging-1-aws.xxx.com;
      ssl_certificate /etc/agora/ap.staging-1-aws.xxx.com.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/agora/ap.staging-1-aws.xxx.com.key;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1111;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Early-Data $ssl_early_data;

        # cors
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
          add_header 'Timing-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,X-Packet-Service-Type,X-Packet-URI,X-User-Address,XD-User-Address,X-Request-From,X-Response-Format' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' '1728000' always;
          add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
          add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000';
          add_header x-quic 'h3';
          return 200;
        }

        if ($request_method ~* '(GET|POST|DELETE|PUT)') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
          add_header 'Timing-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
          add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
          add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000';
          add_header x-quic 'h3';
        }
   }

   server {
        xxxxxxxxxxx
   }
}
```

Comment: Are session tickets enabled (they're the mechanism TLSv1.3 uses for session resumption)? Does TLSv1.3 resume ok over TCP (```openssl s_client -connect SERVER:443 -sess_out session.dat -sess_in session.dat -early_data HTTP_REQUEST.txt```)?

Comment: Yes,
```nginx
ssl_session_tickets on;
ssl_early_data on;
```
had enabled, if i set `worker_processes` as 1 , 0-RTT  works fine

Comment: So, just checking: with multiple workers, TCP TLSv1.3 RTT works fine, but QUIC RTT does not?